# NSLog statement for debugging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nslog

How to write NSLog statement for

```
pageCache.dataSource = value;
```

to debug it.

In debugging found that

```
dataSource = (objc_object*) 0x000000
 isa(objc_class*)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSLog statement to print an object to console is like this

NSLog(@"%@", pageCache.dataSource);

Answer (score 4):

This means that you dataSource is `nil` (i.e. there is nothing there, the pointer doesn't point to anything).  This is probably the cause of whatever you are trying to debug.  Make sure you are properly allocating and initializing your dataSource, or properly setting its pointer value before trying to use it.